# how to delete last digit of a string with a integer VB

Tags: vb.net

How can I delete the last digit of a chain when my chain is on the counter `i` and I want to replace it with another counter?

Here's what I have so far:

```
 For a = 0 To lstbxAdd.Items.Count - 1
            xx = lstbxAdd.Items(a)
            Select Case RTrim(dgvTest.Item(1, i).Value)

                Case xx
                    stFuente.Value = numID.Text 
dgvTest.Item(3, i).Value &= stFuente.Value
```

Comment: You are using i for the listbox index and the datagridview row?

Comment: Could you include some sample strings and expected results?

Comment: @rheitzman yes im using i for the listbox index and the datagriview is here

Answer (score 0):

HELLO TO ALL I COULD FINALLY SOLVE, if anyone has this problem I LEAVE THE CODE

```
Dim stFuente As New VB6.FixedLengthString(7)
    stFuente.Value = Space(7)
    Dim sCampo As New VB6.FixedLengthString(7)
    Dim a As Integer
    Dim xx As String

    Cursor = Cursors.WaitCursor

    For i = 0 To dgvTest.RowCount - 2
        If Len(RTrim(dgvTest.Item(1, i).Value)) <= 6 Then
            GoTo Cambio

        End If
```

Cambio:

```
        Dim vartotal As String

        For a = 0 To lstbxAdd.Items.Count - 1
            xx = lstbxAdd.Items(a)
            Select Case RTrim(dgvTest.Item(1, i).Value)

                Case xx
                    stFuente.Value = numID.Text

                    vartotal = dgvTest.Item(3, i).Value.Substring(0, 6)
                    vartotal = Mid(vartotal, 1, Len(vartotal) - 1)
                    dgvTest.Item(3, i).Value = vartotal
                    dgvTest.Item(3, i).Value &= stFuente.Value

            End Select
        Next

    Next
    Cursor = Cursors.Default
End Sub
```